# Recommended way to create an app-wide menu in Android with Qt

Tags: android, qt

In Harmattan there was a toolbar on the bottom where the app-wide menu could go. In Fremantle the title bar was used for it and in Sailfish there is the pull down menu.

What is the recommended way to create an app-wide menu in Android with Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Qt for Android platform notes:

> The Action Bar is a special Android control that provides many key features including various navigation modes, actions, an options menu, a back button, and also displays the application icon and title.
>
> Unlike Qt Widgets, Qt Quick Controls do not use the native action bar on Android. **ToolBar** and **MenuBar** are offered as a cross-platform replacement. They are unified to a single "action bar" when assigned to the appropriate ApplicationWindow properties.